# Accessing a scripted field in an elasticsearch match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query like the following

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "my_script_field": {
      "script": "..."
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_script_field":"*"
    }
  }
}
```

and it returns empty.

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I can see that the script is actually working by simply retuning everything 
like:

```
{
  "fields": [
  "_source"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "my_script_field": {
      "script": "..."
    }
  },
  "query": {
    match_all: {}
  }
}
```

Example results:

```
  "hits": {
    "total": 1008681,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "logstash-2016.08.27",
        "_type": "traffic",
        "_id": "AVbLDW8qw2vffjMOfTxb",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "@version": "1",
          "@timestamp": "2016-08-27T06:11:46.000Z",
           .................
          }
        },
        "fields": {
          "my_scripted_field": [
            "Asia"
          ]
        }
```

but I cant seem to access it in the query context in any other way.

my question so is:

- Where is the script output saved in memory? (_fields?)
- How to access it via a query? (without copying the script over to a filter script)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: So it seems :( The guys from elastic told me it is not possible.

Comment: For what's worth I'm from Elastic too